# JSON dump breaks my dictionary when using certain characters

Tags: python, json, character, dump

Dumping data into a file with json.dump.
The data looks like this:

```
{"hello": {"this": 1, "a": 1, "is": 1, "test": 1}}
```

The code I use to achieve this is as follows (worddict is a file, something like file.json):

```
with open(words, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(worddict, fp)
fp.close()
```

I'd like to have the data in this format:

```
{
"hello": {
    "a": 1,
    "is": 1,
    "test": 1,
    "this": 1
}
```

I changed the code to this:

```
with open(words, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(worddict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
fp.close()
```

And it works, until I try to dump characters "Á", "É", "Ű"...
These characters breaks the worddict file, and when I cat the file it looks like this:

```
{
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem.  See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    json.dump(worddict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

with

```
    json.dump(worddict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code snippet in both python2 and python3.
In python3, it gave me no errors.

I ran the following code:

```
import json

words = 'a.txt'
worddict = {"hello": {"this": 1, "a": 1, "is": 1, "test": "Á"}}
with open(words, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(worddict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

and got as output:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "a": 1,
        "is": 1,
        "test": "\u00c1",
        "this": 1
    }
}
```

But in python2, I ran into errors. I got a link describing the error:
http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html

The problem occurs in python2 as python2 strings as not unicode by default. So you have to mention encoding at the top of the source code file.
I added "# coding=UTF-8" to the top of the file, before the python source code starts, so as to let python interpreter know the encoding of the file. Once I did that, the code ran in python2 as well as python3 with no errors.
I got the following as output:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "a": 1,
        "is": 1,
        "test": "\u00c1",
        "this": 1
    }
}
```

Here is my full final source code that I used.

```
# coding=UTF-8

import json

words = 'a.txt'
worddict = {"hello": {"this": 1, "a": 1, "is": 1, "test": "Á"}}
with open(words, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(worddict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```